# How to read heap dump file which is created by jconsole?

Tags: java, dump, jconsole

I performed a heap dump manually by invoking the *com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnostic* MXBean's **dumpHeap** operation in jconsole. So I got a dump file.

My question:
Can jconsole read the dump file? If not, which tool can read it? Thanks!

EDIT: Now I know jconsole doesn't provide read feature, I am wondering reason why jconsole only writes dump file without read feature. (This is not my question, I am just curoius about it)

Answer (score 6):

I found an Eclipse plugin [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to read the dump file by myself. Other tools are still welcome.

Comment: FYI- you can also install and run MemoryAnalyzer outside of Eclipse as well if you prefer not to go through the overhead of installing eclipse for this purpose.

Comment: Eclipse MAT is one of the best kept secrets in Java.

Answer (score 6):

You can use jvisualvm.exe which comes with JDK 1.5 and above. Its present in bin folder of JDK. This is a very good tool which can be used to profile even the running Java applications.
You can even use [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to read heap dump files. But this software is licensed.

Comment: jvisualvm is really a good tool for reading ,creating Heap dumps and also analyzing the running application